# Get angle between 2 points

Tags: java, angle

There's a player. While moving cursor Id like to get angle between player and cursor. My code for this is :

```
public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent ev) {
    float angle = (float) Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2(ev.getX() - player.getCenterX(),
            ev.getY() - player.getCenterY()));
    if (angle < 0) {
        angle += 360;
    }
    System.out.println(angle);
}
```

But it doesnt return correct values. How to modify it to return correct values?

Comment: Presumably, you're talking about the angle between two vectors, right?

Comment: So where's your reference point?

Comment: One point is mouse cursor point and second is player point. From both I get coordinates

Comment: Then why are you using `atan2`? Just [take the `arccos` of the dot product divided by the product of the lengths.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angle#Dot_product_and_generalisation)

Comment: From those two points, you get a line segment.  It has a slope, but not an angle, because you need two intersecting lines/segments to have an angle between them.

Comment: I don't fully understand. Could some post code of it?

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
float angle = (float) Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2(-(ev.getX() - player.getCenterX()), ev.getY() - player.getCenterY()));
angle += 90;
```

Comment: Why use float and not double? Why not use arccos as Jack Maney suggests?

Comment: Because he used float and wrote my answer as Jack Maney posted his. Also I used similar code as i was making a game myself ^_^